# File transfer from Android Device to PC over USB programatically

Tags: android, android-usb

I am tying to transfer a file from Android device to PC via USB from my App. For this, can any one help me how to transfer the files and communicate with the PC from my Android App.

Comment: Can you to use the adb?! Open terminal and execute the command: adb push /path/to/local/file

Comment: can we run the adb commands from Android App @TiagoBarreto

Comment: Nope, it is as always controlled by the pc, though you can tunnel requests from the phone through a tunnel initiated by the PC.

Comment: But, I want to transfer a file from Device PC..over USB...How can I do..can u help me...@ChrisStratton